# How to use django-filter with django-select2?

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters, django-select2

I want to implement a field with autocomplete input (django-select2) in the Filterset form (django-filter):

```
import django_filters
from django_select2.forms import Select2Widget

from .models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product','manufacturer']
        widgets = {'product':Select2Widget()}
```

or this:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    product = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
         queryset=Product.objects.all(),
         widget=Select2Widget)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product','manufacturer']
```

These ways don't work. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I didnt find this in the docs. But you must include include the form media in your template: {{ filter.form.media }}.